# Is there an accepted way to have a function pop a value from a parameter?

Tags: python, dictionary, side-effects

Essentially, I would like to know if I should be attempting to avoid side effects in functions if possible, or if side effects are acceptable in certain situations.  I would like to have a function which `pop`s and returns a key from a dictionary and am curious if the function should return just the key:

```
def popkey(d):
    k, v = d.popitem()
    return k

mykey = popkey(d)
```

or if it should also return the modified dictionary:

```
def popkey(d):
    k, v = d.popitem()
    return k, d

mykey, d = popkey(d)
```

More specifically, I have something like the following, where I need keep looking through the dictionary, so I wanted to `pop` the keys as they are paired with the elements from a list.

```
def pop_nearest(d, pt):
    """Pops the key in `d` which is nearest to pt."""
    to_pop = min(d.iterkeys(), key=lambda a: abs(a - pt))
    d.pop(to_pop)

pts = [1,3,5,7,9]
for pt in pts:
    nearest_pt = pop_nearest(d, pt)
    # do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to return the parameter, since you already have a reference to it at the call site.

If you choose to implement `pop_nearest` as a method in a `dict` subclass, then it's sometimes a good idea (depending on what you are trying to achieve) to return `self` so you can chain calls.

```
class MyDict(dict):
   ...
   def pop_nearest(self, pt):
     ...
     return self

...
x = mydict.pop_nearest(1).pop_nearest(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the modified dictionary. It is modified in the function like you would think since it is a reference/pointer to the actual object and not a deep copy and will exist in its modified form in the calling function after pop is called. Returning the key should be sufficient and work how you want it to.